# Recursively Defined Entities

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms, recursion

So I am having some trouble understanding how one is to come up with the recursive  definition to the following problem...

**We are given a rectangle of width $2$ and length $n$. Suppose we have dominoes of size $2\times 1$. What is the number of different ways we can cover the $2\times n$ rectangle?**

The solution is suppose to be $a(n) = a(n-1) + a(n-2)$ but I'm not understanding exactly how they have arrived at that. I can plug values in and see that it does indeed work but what the intuition is behind that is what confuses me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a corner, you have two possibilities to place a domino, either vertical

```
|x|...
|x|...
```

which leaves you with an $(n-1)×2$ rectangle to tile, or horizontally

```
xx...
.....
```

which forces a horizontal domino below

```
xx...
yy...
```

and leaves you with an $(n-2)×2$ rectangle.

Comment: Ok so how does that translate into a(n)=a(n−1)+a(n−2)

Comment: You have two choices to place the domino in the top left corner. One leaves you with an $(n-1)×2$ rectangle, that means $a(n-1)$ ways to complete the tiling, the other leaves you with an $(n-2)×2$ rectangle, that means $a(n-2)$ ways to complete the tiling.

Comment: Alright its finally clicked for me, Thanks a lot!